# Why is any of the answers valid?

Tags: discussion

So I was about to flag a question as a duplicated when this warning showed up.

[[image: Warning when flagging]]

I went to see which flags had been declined and why when I saw that both declined flags where "not an answer" flags, on these two answers:

[Answer #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40777695/azure-service-bus-queue-error-in-the-logic-app/41575332#41575332) by [Atin Agarwal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7400833/atin-agarwal)
[Answer #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25734636/generate-c-sharp-interface-from-c-using-swig/41616826#41616826) by [james](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7410482/james)

I thought these two answers fit better as comments. Why are they considered answers?

#### EDIT

Apparently, the author of the second answer deleted his account and it is no longer available. I don't know if users with high rep or moderators can see deleted answers, if so, it'd be nice if one of them can attach a print here.

Comment: What, is it Thursday already? I guess it's time for another NAA discussion.

Comment: Actually a mod deleted the second answer 11 minutes ago.

Comment: The first one is proposing an answer to the question.  It doesn't seem like a particularly *good* answer to me, but it is *An Answer*.  The second was likely just a misclick, as it has since been corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because both of them *attempt to answer the question*. Exhibit one:

> Check if Session is enabled on the Queue.

is self-explanatory. It might be completely, 100% wrong, but it's still obviously an *attempt* to answer. Edit, downvote, and comment, but don't flag.

Exhibit two:

> had this problem if I didn't implement all virutal c++ methods - SWIG stopped

This has its grammar problems, yes. Let me rearrange some words:

> (I) had this problem if I didn't implement all (the) (virtual) c++ methods(:) "SWIG stopped".

From this, I infer that the answerer believes the problem can be solved by implementing these methods. It's an attempt to answer. It should be edited, possibly downvoted, but not flagged.

Comment: On the second one you have to infer a bloody lot to see an answer in that ...

Comment: @rene We don't need to see a correct answer; only an *attempt* to answer. In this case, Flexo has domain knowledge and I'm respecting his decision to delete.

Comment: I'm not disrespecting his decision or your explanation to it. I'm only saying that you have to stretch your imagination to great length. That is something to keep in mind.

Comment: @rene Do you though?  Saying, "I had this problem too and I fixed it by doing X" is just a slightly noisier way of saying, "You can fix this problem by doing X."  The noise of "I also had this problem" doesn't turn it into NAA.

Comment: Yes, my English language comprehension isn't that well established and needs constant adjustment and learning sessions @Servy so your explanation helps in that sense, thanks.

Comment: Is "your code is wrong" also an "attempt to answer" that moderators will not delete?

Comment: @Cody That doesn't attempt to provide an answer, no. If you want to debate the policy, that belongs in a new question.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait. What? If you're going to have a policy like this, it at least needs to be consistent. Can you explain to me how "check if session is enabled" is different from "your code is wrong" in terms of attempting to provide an answer? It is clearly an attempt, and it very likely is the answer to most questions.